# Amazon AWS Machine Learning HTTP request

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, httprequest, amazon-machine-learning

I have created AWS Machine Learning model with working real-time endpoint. I want to consume created service via HTTP request. For testing purpose I'm using Postman, I've created request according to Amazon's API documentation but every time I get the same exception: `UnknownOperationException`. While I'm using Python SDK the service is working fine. Below example that gets model info.

That's my request (fake credentials):

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: realtime.machinelearning.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
Content-Type: application/json
X-Amz-Target: AmazonML_20141212.GetMLModel
X-Amz-Date: 20170714T124250Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=JNALSFNLANFAFS/20170714/us-east-1/AmazonML/aws4_request, SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, Signature=fiudsf9sdfh9sdhfsd9hfsdkfdsiufhdsfoidshfodsh
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: hd9sfh9s-idsfuuf-a32c-31ca-dsufhdso

{
   "MLModelId": "ml-Hfdlfjdof0807",
   "Verbose": true
}
```

Exception I get:

```
{
    "Output": {
        "__type": "com.amazon.coral.service#UnknownOperationException",
        "message": null
    },
    "Version": "1.0"
}
```

Comment: Your content type should be `application/x-amz-json-1.1`

Comment: @jjones doesn't work, now I get this error: `"__type": "UnknownOperationException"`

Comment: review the documentation here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/machine-learning/latest/APIReference/API_GetMLModel.html

Comment: I will note though, that the AWS documentation is notoriously awful. Their HTTP request samples often have invalid values.

Comment: Totally agree, I've gone through entire documentation but still couldn't find a solution. I had no problems with their API Gateway but while dealing with ML service I can't execute even a simple request.

Comment: Instead of using a POST request, do it as a GET request. I just tested it as a post and got the same unknownoperationexception, but when I changed it to a GET, I got a missingauthenticationtokenexception, which possibly means it would work if I had the right authentication key.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After doing research on AWS forum I've found some similar HTTP requests. Turns out I had 3 incorrect parameters.

1. Host address should be:

`Host: machinelearning.us-east-1.amazonaws.com`

2. Content type:

`Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1`

3. In credentials parameters target service has to be specified as `machinelearning`

---

Short instruction how to setup Postman's request:

1. In `Authorization` tab choose `AWS Signature` and fill in `AccessKey` and `SecrectKey`. In `Service Name` field write `machinelearning`. Click `Update Request`, this will update your header.
2. In `Headers` tab add two headers:

   Key: `X-Amz-Target`, Value: `AmazonML_20141212.GetMLModel`

   Key: `Content-Type`, Value: `application/x-amz-json-1.1`
3. Add body:

`{ "MLModelId": "YOUR_ML_MODEL_ID",  "Verbose": true }`

---

Correct HTTP request below:

```
POST  HTTP/1.1
Host: machinelearning.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
X-Amz-Target: AmazonML_20141212.GetMLModel
Content-Type: application/x-amz-json-1.1
X-Amz-Date: 20170727T113217Z
Authorization: AWS4-HMAC-SHA256 Credential=JNALNFAFS/20170727/us-east-1/machinelearning/aws4_request, 
SignedHeaders=content-length;content-type;host;x-amz-date;x-amz-target, 
Signature=fiudsf9sdfh9sdhfsd9hfsdkfdsiufhdsfoidshfodsh
Cache-Control: no-cache
Postman-Token: hd9sfh9s-idsfuuf-a32c-31ca-dsufhdso

{
   "MLModelId": "ml-Hfdlfjdof0807",
   "Verbose": true
}
```

Comment: After I did the above, when trying to use real-time prediction, I was getting error: `"class com.amazon.coral.value.json.numbers.TruncatingBigNumber can not be converted to an String"`. This turned out to be because Machine Learning requires numbers in the JSON to be encoded as strings. (or maybe this is always true of x-amz-json-1.1? I can't find any spec for that particular flavor of JSON...)

Answer (score 0):

Please check following link and validate your sigv4

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/sigv4_signing.html